# Show Lightning component Modal above Salesforce Global header (Position Issue)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, slds, modal

I have added lightning Modal (slds) component A in a another Lightning Component B. 
Lightning component B is used to create Lightning Tab.

Now when I show the modal, Position of Modal component A is restricted inside Parent component B.
I would like to display modal above global Header (outside Component A) as in attached screenshot.
CSS z-index is not much helpful, may be i am wrong.
Please help to fix this position issue. 
Thanks for your time.`

---

Followed - Markup From SLDS Page (Summer ’17)

```
<div class="slds">
    <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="modal-content-id-2" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-2" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
        <div class="slds-modal__container">
            <header class="slds-modal__header"></header>
        </div>
    <!-- Modal Content -->
    </section>
    <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
</div>
```

---

[image: Portion of Modal hidden under Global Header]
[image: Expected]

Comment: Have you done all the necessary SLDS markup as shown here?
https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/modals/
I thought using slds-modal__container will automatically use the right z-index?

Comment: @ChristianMenzinger 
Yes, I followed the same documentation. 
In fact the same markup is working as expected when I had this Modal component inside a lightning component which was in-turn added to Visual force page but Not to Lightning Tab.

Comment: Added Markup to Question

Comment: Style tag is not allowed in lightning components from ver42.
Try Lightning component : [**overlayLibrary**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_lightning_overlayLibrary.htm?search_text=overlayLibrary)
 .

There are still ways to add custom css using aura:unescapedHtml but **not advisable**. <aura:unescapedHtml value="{!v.cssStyle}"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was solved earlier. [Issue in Lightning desing System modal component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/133619/issue-in-lightning-desing-system-modal-component?rq=1)

Additional thing to take care is to revert change by applying css "as it was" while closing the modal.

Verified how it is being done (Salesforce Standard) to show New Object Record (Ex: Account) Modal.
Header z-index has been made to 0 and 
.forceStyle.desktop .viewport class overflow to hidden.

### Markup

```
<aura:attribute name="cssStyle" type="String" />
<style>{!v.cssStyle}</style>  
<!-- Style tag is considered as root element if this is the first line in Markup. Make sure you have this at the end (just before </aura:component>) if you have any js functions which works on root element css -->
```

### Helper Js

```
applyCSS: function(component){
    component.set("v.cssStyle", ".forceStyle .viewport .oneHeader.slds-global-header_container {z-index:0} .forceStyle.desktop .viewport{overflow:hidden}");
},
revertCssChange: function(component){
    component.set("v.cssStyle", ".forceStyle .viewport .oneHeader.slds-global-header_container {z-index:5} .forceStyle.desktop .viewport{overflow:visible}");
}
```

Comment: when reverting (closing modal), it is better to nullify v.cssStyle attribute

revertCssChange: function(component){
    component.set("v.cssStyle",  null);
}

Comment: It does not allow me to use `<style>` tag: `Failed to save FilePreview.cmp: Markup for markup://cg:FilePreview may not contain a <style> tag: Source`

Comment: @efirat 
Yes, Style tag is not allowed in lightning components from ver42.
Try Lightning component : [overlayLibrary](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_lightning_overlayLibrary.htm?search_text=overlayLibrary)
 .

There are still ways to add custom css using aura:unescapedHtml but not advisable. <aura:unescapedHtml value="{!v.cssStyle}"/>. Try lightning component.

Comment: I have added style tag by changing component api version to 41. Thanks..