# How to get HTML DOM element outside of lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css, modal

I have a lightning component with a modal that opens over it.

I want to open this modal on the entire page viewport height and view port width -
 meaning on top of the lightning experience header.

I use the [Strike modal component](http://www.lightningstrike.io/#!/strikeModal) that is using this markup to disable the background of the modal:

```
<div id="backdrop" aura:id="backdrop" class="{!'slds-backdrop ' + if(v.fadeIn, 'slds-backdrop--open', '')}"></div>
```

But with this code, the disabled background does not go over the lightning experience headers as you can see here:

[image]

How can I hide the header?

Comment: It's because the `z-index` of the header is 5 as default.
You can find the header in the page and apply `z-index` as 0 or less. You can hide it behind the backdrop. Inspect the page get id or other findable attribute of the header.

Comment: check this answer https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/141910/18731

Comment: Also this answer https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/178549/18731

Comment: @RatanPaul that's Great

Comment: Thanks for the response :) I saw this solution and wanted to know if there is more elegant way of doing this (maybe even standard by Salesforce?)